# What good is a decoy grenade in hardcore matches? Do they fool anything else like sentry guns?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

If you use the decoy grenade in a hardcore match, what happens? Since the players don't have a hud, it seems like a decoy grenade would be useless.

Also do they fool sentry guns or Cobra helicopters? Do they show up on Huey or attack helicopter hud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends entirely on their use, and your strategy.

While Hardcore players generally rely heavily on sound, the sound of  decoys are far too obvious. As well, with no radar, you might actually confuse your own teammates.

However, if you don't use ghost, then a decoy is a nice way to add a little chaos during a spy plane. Since radar is so rare, many hardcore players literally stare at it as soon as it pops up, and don't think their actions through. You can bait the fire for a coupke easy kills if you keep moving.

You can also use decoys on tactical game modes if planned correctly. It takes a couple moments to realize the fire is a decoy, so If one team mate throws a decoy on the east side of a flag it may open an opportunity to sweep in from the west, clear the area, and steal the flag.

Even if they dont work, their fire is noisy and makes it harder to listen for footsteps and real gunfire, so even against experienced players it isnt a total waste.

In the end, it depends on the team you are playing. I usually keep one extra class on the side with decoys, and try them once or twice to see if they work. Experienced players ignore them, but it covers your real fire. Inexperienced players eat them up, and you reap serious rewards as they run madly around searching. Your milage may vary :)

Answer (score 5):

Decoy grenades can be used to fool attack dogs.  They will go after the decoy grenade instead of attacking you.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea!

Answer (score 1):

Hardcore players rely significantly more on sound due to the lack of HUD.  This means the decoy still has a use in hardcore matches!  By throwing a decoy you can either 'bait' another player or force him to turn around for an easy kill.  As far as I know the decoy is only seen by the HUD during a spy plane, they do not fool sentry guns or helicopters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with decoys on hardcore is, well, they are so obviously decoys! The pattern they fire and plus the fact they are constantly bursting with unsupressed fire. No good player would play like that. They are so much more useful for baiting in normal, I never bother with them in Hardcore.